# Input values into a list and loop until argument is given

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

Im trying to make a loop that lets a user enter a list of entries and once he doesnt type anything (just presses enter) it exits the loop.
I want each entry given by the user to be added to a list.

```
while(True):
    to_addr = ['']
    appnd = input('Type in the recipient: ')
    to_addr.append(appnd)
    print(to_addr)
```

Comment: And what exactly are you having trouble with? What did you try so far? please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify and include any code you've already written. See [ask].

Comment: yes, sorry. i just felt that my code was so far off that it wasn't worth adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple while True loop should do the trick :)

```
value_list = []
value = ""
while True:
    value = input("Enter your value: ")
    if not value:
        break
    else:
        value_list.append(value)

print(value_list)
```